# gridstack select content rather than dragging

Tags: text, selection, copy-paste, gridstack

I am using gridstack to render variable content onto a website. I need to render a table and some text inside the grid element, which works fine so far. BUT I want to allow the user to select portions of the rendered table text or other plain text with copy and paste but gridstack does not allow the selection it just drags the widget. Is there a way to make a handle bar visible and to allow only the dragging when the user selects the handlebar not the content ?

Answer (score 1):

It should work to override the handle selector in the 'draggable' options, e.g:

```
GridStack.init({
  draggable: {
    handle: '.your-handle-class',
  }
});
```

https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/tree/develop/doc#updateel-gridstackelement-opts-gridstackwidget

Comment: Well, this does supply me a text select cursor but I still cannot select any content. Any other hint?

Comment: Hm, the only way I've found to make text selectable is either to embed a text-area, or disable the drag-and-drop altogether with:
staticGrid: true
It might not be ideal for your case, but I guess I'd either make a toggle for layout editing, or add a "copy text" button.

Comment: actually I wanted it in the way like grafana does it with a header bar handle rather than the drag via the the complete widget

Answer (score 0):

Add

onMouseDown='event.stopPropagation();'

To any element you don't want to be able to drag with grid stack.

:)